# extract two tags instead of one from xml file

Tags: python, xpath, sax, xmllint

I have this code that is working correctly.

It extracts all the titles of wikipedia articles.

```
import bz2
import xml.sax
import xml.sax.handler

class Handler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__buffer = None

    def characters(self, data):
        if self.__buffer is None:
            return
        self.__buffer.append(data)

    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == 'title':
            self.__buffer = []

    def endElement(self, name):
        if self.__buffer is None:
            return
        print(repr(name), repr(''.join(self.__buffer)))
        self.__buffer = None

with bz2.open('/home/mrwiki-20210701-pages-meta-current.xml.bz2', 'r') as stream:
    xml.sax.parse(stream, Handler())
```

I am trying to extract the **bytes** parameter of "text" field along with the "title".
This will not work because I need only "bytes" and not the actual text.

```
if name == 'title':
    self.__buffer = []
if name == 'text':
    self.__buffer = []
```

Here is a sample record...

```
myfile = """
<mediawiki xmlns="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/expo
rt-0.10/ http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10.xsd" version="0.10" xml:lang="mr">
  <siteinfo>
    <sitename>xyz</sitename>
    <dbname>mrwiki</dbname>
    <base>https://xx.wikipedia.org/wiki/xxxxxxxxxx</base>
    <generator>MediaWiki 1.37.0-wmf.11</generator>
    <case>first-letter</case>
    <namespaces>
      <namespace key="-2" case="first-letter">मिडिया</namespace>
      <namespace key="2303" case="case-sensitive">Gadget definition talk</namespace>
    </namespaces>
  </siteinfo>
  <page>
    <title>my_title </title>
    <ns>0</ns>
    <id>1</id>
    <revision>
      <id>1857942</id>
      <parentid>1629326</parentid>
      <timestamp>2020-12-26T11:34:51Z</timestamp>
      <contributor>
        <username>andesh9822</username>
        <id>66586</id>
      </contributor>
      <model>wikitext</model>
      <format>text/x-wiki</format>
      <text bytes="5823" xml:space="preserve"> some text
 </text>
      <sha1>11z9foqntwoukfd4xfjnfhpc9y33r25</sha1>
    </revision>
  </page>

"""
```

> Current: my_title
>
> Expected: my_title 5823

Comment: did you try using `attr.getValue('bytes')`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.sax.reader.html#xml.sax.xmlreader.Attributes.getValue

Comment: The question has nothing to do with XPath or xmllint. Those tags don't belong here.

Comment: Handle the container element, the `page` element, to set up your buffer or any other data structure to store the `title` and `text`, then fill it while handling those elements and print it while handling the end element for the `text` or for the `page` element.

Comment: I thought the same can be achieved using XPath and xmllint more elegantly. If that is not the case then I will remove those tags.

Comment: Getting the value of an attribute (`bytes` in this case) is a common task. There are many ways to process XML. Do you use SAX for performance reasons (very large XML file)?

Comment: Yes. I tried python because the file is large. When that did not work, I tried xmllint and xpath on 4.xlarge ec2 instance. But I did not get expected results. I am simply trying to extract title and bytes fields from this file. wget https://dumps.wikimedia.org/mrwiki/20210701/mrwiki-20210701-pages-meta-current.xml.bz2

Comment: Why did you remove relevant tags? The question is about Python and SAX. You have not asked a question about XPath or xmllint. You just added the tags and wrote in a comment: "I tried xmllint and xpath on 4.xlarge ec2 instance. But I did not get expected results". Again, if you need help with those tools, please post a separate question (and don't forget to include a [mcve]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do it with ElementTree and [`iterparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse):

```
import bz2
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET
 
with bz2.open("mrwiki-20210701-pages-meta-current.xml.bz2", "r") as stream:
    for _, elem in ET.iterparse(stream):
        if elem.tag == "{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}title":
            print(elem.text)
        if elem.tag == "{http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/}text":
            print(elem.get("bytes"))
        elem.clear()
```

`iterparse()` builds up a tree structure that will use a lot of memory. `elem.clear()` remedies that by removing all content from the elements once they have been processed.

The elements in the XML file are bound to the `http://www.mediawiki.org/xml/export-0.10/` namespace. This must be taken into account.

---

And here is SAX-based code that does the same.

```
import bz2
import xml.sax
import xml.sax.handler
 
class Handler(xml.sax.handler.ContentHandler):
    def characters(self, data):
        self.__buffer = data
 
    def startElement(self, name, attrs):
        if name == "title":
            self.__buffer = ""
        if name == "text":
            self.__buffer2 = attrs.getValue("bytes")
            
    def endElement(self, name):
        if name == "title":
            print(self.__buffer)
        if name == "text":
            print(self.__buffer2)
 
with bz2.open("mrwiki-20210701-pages-meta-current.xml.bz2", "r") as stream:
    xml.sax.parse(stream, Handler())
```

A SAX parser consumes very little memory as it just reports events as they occur.

By default, `xml.sax.handler.feature_namespaces` is false, which means that namespace-related events aren't reported by the parser. It is as if there was no namespace.

Comment: This is correct. But I will wait before accepting the answer because I want to know if it is easier to use xpath or xmllint command.

Comment: I don't know if any other method will be easier. Please ask about one problem at a time. The question is about Python and SAX. If you need help with XPath and/or xmllint, please post a separate question about that.